Zeppelin JDBC interpreter SQL port issue
I'm trying to import some hive functions from ESRI to do some geospatial data science, but keep getting an error message. The input is on a zeppelin notebook.
I ran the line:
%sql create temporary function st_bin as 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Bin'

expecting for the notebook to properly import the function.
However, I get output:
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

